# How can I change "Mount Point" that has been changed to normal?

Tags: linux, osx, kali-linux

previously I has been trying to install Kali Linux on my usb.

Now here is the problem, I have used the command

```
sudo dd if=kali.dmg of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=512k
```

which I think it changed or **replaced** my OS X main drive. 
I still believe that my OS X drive still exists because the "hard drive" icon that I modified still appeared on the screen.

[image]

I decided to check all the drives on my laptop and here is the result using
`df` on terminal and here is the result.

[image]

Does any if these is my OS X that has been replaced?

PS. I checked this by install new OS X on external hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `dd`'d it to your actual drive's partition, then what you're seeing on the bootloader is simply an entry for an OS that doesn't exist anymore. `dd`, unfortunately, does not change or replace anything except the data. It's a low level **copy/replace** utility with tons of features.

In **Mac OS X** the drives are denoted as `/dev/diskX` where `X` is an integer. The partitions are denoted as `/dev/diskXsX` where `X` is also an integer.
Also, the `raw` files to the hard drives and to the partitions are `/dev/rdiskX` and `/dev/rdiskXsX` respectively.

From the `man hdiutil` on Mac, you get the following.

> /dev/rdisk nodes are character-special devices, but are "raw" in the
>   BSD sense and force block-aligned I/O.  They are closer to the
>   physical disk than the buffer cache.  /dev/disk nodes, on the other
>   hand, are buffered block-special devices and are used primarily by the
>   kernel's filesystem code.

In simple terms, you just overwritten your hard drive and you did it in the most efficient and fastest way possible by using `rdisk` instead of `disk`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. So there is no way I can recover my OS X right?

Comment: Not easily, no, unfortunately. Next time don't use dd. Disk2 seems your OS X on the external and disk1 is now an image of Kali.

Comment: @user4450191 if you have backups of your OS, specifically time machine backups, you can use those to go back to where you were before you did this last step.